# Why python requests get a 404 error?

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, python-requests

I try to use `requests` library to get a content from an URL. In more details, I do it in the following way:

```
import requests

proxies = {'http':'my_proxy.blabla.com/'}
r = requests.get(url, proxies = proxies)
print r.text
```

As a result I get the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>404 - Not Found</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

So, it looks like the proxy let me go and I reached the server. However, the web server was unable to interpret my request (wrong path or so) and did not know what content to return. Do I interpret it correctly?

What can be the reason for that? I do get the expected content if I put the URL in one of my browsers.

**ADDED**

It has been suggested in the comments that the root of the problem is in the headers. So, I used this web site: http://www.procato.com/my+headers/ to find out what headers are sent by my browser. I used these values to set the `headers` variable given to the `requests.get` function. I set the values for the following keys: 'User-Agent', 'Accept', 'Referer', 'Accept-Encoding', 'Accept-Language', 'X-Forwarded-For', 'Cache-Control', 'Connection'. Unfortunately, it does not resolve the problem. I am still getting the same 404 response.

**ADDED 2**

I have tested my function for tow different URLs and got exactly the same response. So, my previous assumption that the responses (XML that I see) comes from the web-server is probably wrong. It is unlikely that two completely different web-servers (one of them was Google) generate the same responses.

So, now I do not understand where the XML comes from. Can it be that it comes from the proxy server?

Comment: The server could reject delivering the content if it does not like the "user agent" identification. It's not nice to respont with a 404 error in this case but maybe the intention is to fool search engines, or maybe the server wants robots to get a completely different idea of the site, hence the 404.

Comment: Can I somehow set "user agent" so that the requests coming from Python look the same as those coming from Firefox or Chromium. I am asking because requests form browsers are accepted by the web server and it delivers some content. In other words, can Python pretend to be a browser? I suppose that I need something like: `headers={'User-Agent': 'firefox'}`

Comment: Something along these lines. But the strings are a bit longer. Please use your favourite search engine and/or Python documentation; you'll easily find the answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
URL = 'https://www.blahblah.com'
proxy = {'http': 'http://www.blahblah.com'}
r = requests.get(URL, proxies = proxy)
print r.text
```

Comment: Sorry, but I did not get you solution. How is it different from what I am doing? Do you suggest to use the same address for URL and proxy?

Comment: You have written incomplete URL in proxy dictionary.

Comment: You mean that `http://` is missing in front of the proxy URL? I tired to put `http://` in front of the proxy URL, it does not change anything. I think it is not necessary since we have already `http` as the key.

Comment: I have tested this with google.com and it works fine!

Comment: I also tried it for Google and I get exactly the same XML (with 404 error) as before. So, now I think that the XML comes not from the web server but from my proxy server. So, I use correct URL of the proxy server (it is why I am able to speak to it and get something from it) but probably it needs more (maybe username and password).

Comment: Hm..You need username and password for that.